# Will my RAM be compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, compatibility, computer-building

I'm trying to buy some RAM for my PC and I have noticed that when buying it is named **BLT8G4D26AFTA** whereas on my motherboard's compatibility list it says **BLT8G4D26AFTA.16FAD** would the .16FAD on the end of the second make any difference to the compatability with a motherboard?

================ LINKS AND INFO ================

Motherboard: GA-A320M-HD2

CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 - YD1200BBAEBOX

Mobo: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-HD2-rev-10

Mobo compatibility lists: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-HD2-rev-10#support-doc

Mobo compatibility list for CPU: http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-a320m-hd2.pdf

CPU: https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-3-1200

CPU drivers and support page: https://www.amd.com/en/support/cpu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-3-desktop-processors/amd-ryzen-3-1200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a shortened name but it's the same. These compatibility lists only tell you what RAM modules were tested by the manufacturer with that motherboard. But it's not an exclusive list and there is a 99% chance that any 4/8/16GB, 2667/2400/2133 MHz, DDR4 RAM will work just fine if you don't want to overclock.

Answer (score 1):

The `.16FAD` probably won't make much of a difference - consumer RAM tends to be fairly universal and the compatibility list only shows RAM modules that's been tested with the mobo.

Pretty much all non-ECC, DIMM (RAM in the desktop form factor), DDR4 RAM clocked at 2666MHz or lower should work (but 2666MHz is recommended) with your CPU and motherboard.

Good luck!